# Securing MVC4 with the AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been learning about how to secure asp.net MVC4 applications but something confuses me concerning the use of the **AuthorizeAttribute**

(One of the blogs that nicely explains securing MVC is [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx))

To lock down all controllers by default, the **AuthorizeAttribute** is added to **RegisterGlobalFilters**

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

But I'm also seeing examples where something similar is done in the global.asax file:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute());
```

I understand that the first statement is to lock down the MVC controllers and the second is to lock down the WebAPI controllers, but when is the second statement needed? If I'm not building WebApi controllers, is the second statement still necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that the first statement is to lock down the MVC controllers and the second is to lock down the WebAPI controllers....If I'm not building WebApi controllers, is the second statement still necessary?

I think this is one of those questions were deep down you know the answer but want a definitive answer....so here it is - No.